# What does a derivative with respect to metric mean?

Tags: differential-geometry

What's the difference between the derivative with respect to metric and the derivative with respect to one of the coordinates?

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial g_{ab}} or \frac{\partial }{\partial g^{ab}} vs \frac{\partial }{\partial x^{i}}or \frac{\partial }{\partial x_{i}}$$

Comment: Can you provide some context? I'm not sure I've seen that notation before..

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_derivative

Comment: Derivatives with respect to coordinates are the usual derivatives of functions on a manifold. Derivatives with respect to the metric are not common - additional context would be needed to know exactly what's going on here. If the quantity being differentiated is just a pointwise function of the metric then it's just the usual partial derivative, but if it's e.g. a function of the metric and its derivatives it may be a variational/functional/Gateaux derivative of some form.

Answer (score 0):

Given a tensor-valued field $\phi$ it is easy to form expressions involving $\phi$ and its covariant derivatives. It is certainly meaningful then to ask what is the change in such an expression when you vary one of the components of the metric, for a specific point in spaces and a specific value of the metric.

For example, with $\phi^a$ a covariant vector field, and $g_{ab}$ some non-trivial metric (say the Schwartzchild metric, you could ask about 
$$
\phi^a_{;a}
$$
where ; denotes a covariant derivative (which depends on the Christofel symbols, which in turn depend on the metric).  And then some contrived variational problem might have you solving for something like
$$
\phi_a \phi_b \frac{d\phi^c_{;c}}{dg_{ab}} = 0
$$
This is a rather contrive usefulness  I have, however, seen methods involving derivatives wrt the metric used, for instance, to derive teh Schwartzchild solution, amd to formulated Hamiltonian forms equivalent to GR.